# How do I create a Monero testnet wallet address and account?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, testnet

I have already downloaded the Monero software. It includes `monero-cli-wallet`, `monero-gui-wallet`, `monerod`, `monero-wallet-rpc` etc.

How do I create a new wallet using using these tools?

Using GUI Wallet I am not able to change to Testnet. Is there any way to change the network type?

How do I setup a daemon for a testnet wallet using `monerod`/`monero-wallet-cli`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the command-line tools, all you need to do is add the flag `--testnet` when running them.

For example, to run your daemon: `monerod --testnet`. And when your testnet daemon is fully synced to the testnet network, you can then create a wallet using: `monero-wallet-cli --testnet`.

If you are using the GUI, there is "Testnet" checkbox somewhere. See [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3986/7493).

Comment: Ok, let me check for monerod. I've found that option of testnet for gui wallet inside advance mode fourth options while creating a wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (Linux shell):

```
export NETTYPE=testnet
export WALLET=my-${NETTYPE}-wallet

monerod --detach --${NETTYPE}

monero-wallet-cli --${NETTYPE} \
    --use-english-language-names \
    --generate-new-wallet ${WALLET} \
    --create-address-file \
    --password 'secretpassword'
```

Your public address will be in a file `my-testnet-wallet.address.txt`

**Don't forget to copy your mnemonic seed words to a safe place**

Comment: If not using Linux/Ubantu, is there any process for windows?